# How to get the Specific Data from Spedific Positions from a List of Items?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

> I am scraping a Website, where I am trying to get the `Location`, `Graduation`, `Job type` and `Salary` seperately so that I can use it later.

> This is the Code :

```
r2 = requests.get(link, headers = headers)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.content, 'lxml')
locationPTag = soup2.find_all('p', class_= 'card-meta')
for k in locationPTag:
    getLocation = k.text.strip()
    print(getLocation)
```

> here the `link` is : https://www.karmasandhan.com/public-service-commission-west-bengal-wbpsc-assistant-engineer-jobs-advt-no-21-2020/40261

> Output received is :

```
West Bengal, Multiple Cities
Engineering Diploma/ Degree
Regular
15600 — 42000
```

> This is a Single Item . How can I separate all of them to separate Variables so as to use them individually ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
r2 = requests.get(link, headers = headers)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.content, 'lxml')
locationPTag = soup2.find_all('p', class_= 'card-meta')

Location, Graduation, Job_type, Salary = [k.text.strip() for k in locationPTag]
```